# Android: disable nfc on device

Tags: android, nfc

I noticed the following problem: the user in my application nfc worked when showing the ticket, when he leaned against the turnstile ticket, nfc worked. I want to turn off nfc in my activity. how could I possibly do that? I don't want other apps to react to nfc while my app is running

Comment: @MichaelDodd I don't want to send the user to turn off nfc. I want to block the use of nfc in my application, I read that you can bring your application to the fore in front of others and do nothing at the time of reading

Comment: `I want to turn off nfc in my activity. how could I possibly do that?` - You need to edit your question to make that more clear then. At the moment your question implies you want to turn off NFC on the device, but your comment "block the use of  NFC" is equally unclear. You mean you don't want your app to react to NFC at all?

Comment: @MichaelDodd I don't want other apps to react to nfc while my app is running

Comment: @Nikitc I think dupe still answers your question: *"It's not possible programatically"* (unless the API is pre-16)